# Mongooes query inside foreach not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

this code not working,  `date = 112022`.  i need count of multiple table data with corporateID matching key. and use some math to culculate some more data. problem in query inside foreach. please help in this or  tel if there any better option.

```
router.post('/BWreport', async function(req, res, next){
const month = req.body.date.slice(0, 2);
const year = req.body.date.slice(2, 6);
const nextmonth = parseInt(month) + 1;
try{
var cname = await corporate.find().select('corporateID username').lean();
        cname.forEach(function(c, await){
         c["totalcases"] = verification_req.find({ createdAt: { $gt: year+'-'+month, $lt: year+'-'+nextmonth} }).where({'user_id':c.corporateID}).count();
        });
        return res.json({ response:true, data:cname });
        }catch(err){
        return res.json({ response:false, data:err  });
      }
});
{
"response": false,
"data": {}
}
```

desired output

```
data: [
        {
            "_id": "61d3f90340b6cad5974ca50a",
            "username": "SB Demo",
            "corporateID": "SB00001",
            "totalcases": "0"
        },
        {
            "_id": "62266f20fa0eb7a8fbe7d82a",
            "corporateID": "SB00002",
            "username": "NeoGrowth",
            "totalcases": "1"
        }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use : **for-of Loop** & **countDocuments({})**

```
router.post('/BWreport', async function(req, res, next){

    const month = req.body.date.slice(0, 2);
    const year = req.body.date.slice(2, 6);
    const nextmonth = parseInt(monthno) + 1;
    try{
      var cname = await corporate.find().select('corporateID username').lean();
      for(let c of cname){
         c["totalcases"] = await verification_req.countDocuments({ 'user_id':c.corporateID, createdAt: { $gt: year+'-'+month, $lt: year+'-'+nextmonth}});
      }

      return res.json({ response:true, data:cname });
     }catch(err){
        return res.json({ response:false, data:err  });
     }
});
```

Comment: didn't work, same output

Comment: change  monthno to month and yearno to year .